# Protractor clicking nested elements based on a condition, error - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

I am trying to create a Page Object for one of the Reusable UI Controls we are using in our application, which is a table having bunch of headers(`th`) with buttons to filter. I want to click the button of a particular `th` element. Here is my code

```
this.gridAllColumns = browser.element(by.css('[grid-service=envGridService]')).all(by.tagName('th'));

this.filterColumn = function(columnName){
    gridAllColumns.each(function(element){
        var text = element.getText();
        if( text = columnName){
            console.log(text);
            var buttonElement = element.element(by.tagName('button'));
            buttonElement.click();
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting the below error

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified

What I am doing wrong? Could any one point me in right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the `gridAllColumns` using `this` and you need to use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
this.filterColumn = function(columnName) {
    this.gridAllColumns.filter(function(header) {
        return header.getText().then(function (headerText) {
            return headerText === columnName;
        });
    }).first().element(by.tagName('button')).click();
}
```